# Passing Data to another method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapbox

I am getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(_, _) -> ()' to expected argument type '(Route?, Error?)'

Here is my code:

```
@objc func actionWithoutParam(){
    calculateRoute(from: (MapView.userLocation!.coordinate), to: location) { (route, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the calculate route method:

```
     func calculateRoute(from originCoor: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to destinationCoor: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completion: (Route?, Error?) ) -> Void{
}
```

Comment: Would you mind updating your question by adding syntax of calculateRoute() function?

Comment: It seems your  `calculateRoute` func parameter expects a tuple but you pass a closure to it. But need the whole definition of `calculateRoute` to verify.

Comment: no one can help you until you add your calculateRoute method.

Comment: Hi lads, sorry with time difference I didn't see this until this morning. Ive updated the question with the calculateRoute method handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Closure that you have written is wrong, use this

```
// function creation
    func calculateRoute(from originCorr: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to destinationCorr: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completion: (Route?, Error?) -> Void) {

    }
// function calling
calculateRoute(from: .init(), to: .init()) { (route, error) in

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a missing return type for the closure parameter in `calculateRoute`, change the definition of the closure to

```
(String?, Error?) -> Void
```

Comment: @mick1996 Well I have the same answer as the one you accepted and for me it works.